# is it possible to calculate data between two different cubes?

Tags: ssas, olap, olap-cube

I have two SSAS cubes (wages and sales) in one project. I need to find wages to sales by dividing wages with sales. to achieve that i need to get wages value in wages.cube then dividing it with sales value in sales.cube, is it possible to calculate between two different cubes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not directly in a calculated measure.

Are wages and sales in different cubes because of different security concerns?

It would be more usual to have a wages measure group and a sales measure group in the same cube. You could just add the wages measure group to the Sales cube and hide it from users

Comment: sorry i am new with this, i just realized it was so simple, i didn't think about that lol. thanks. btw how to hide measure group?

Comment: hide the individual measures